# Can child class use a template parent's static methods?

Tags: c++, templates, static-methods

I have a template parent class, and multiple child classes. I want to make a static method that takes any child class and returns a child class, but I want to write that in the parent class, so I don't have to manually write it for each child. How do I do that? I have:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class Parent
{
public:
    T x;
    T y;

    static Parent Inverse(Parent* A)
    {
        Parent B;
        B.x = -(A->x);
        B.y = -(A->y);
        return B;
    }
};

class Child1 : public Parent<int>{
};

class Child2 : public Parent<float>{
};

class ChildN : public Parent<double>{
};

int main()
{
    Child2 A;
    A.x = 3.14;
    A.y = 15.92;
    Child2 B = Child2::Inverse(&A);
    cout << B.x << " : " << B.y << endl;
}
```

I get an error "conversion from 'Parent' to non-scalar type 'Child2' requested.
I tried to do it as:

```
Child2 B = Child2::Inverse<float>(&A);
```

Then I get "expected primary-expression before 'float'.
I also tried:

```
Child2 B = Parent<float>::Inverse(&A);
```

Then I get the same error as the 1-st time "conversion from 'Parent' to non-scalar type 'Child2' requested".

It works fine if I wrote the static method for each child. But I wanna know what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the statement...

```
Child2 B = Child2::Inverse(&A);
```

`Child2::Inverse` has return type `Parent` so you are trying to implicitly convert a `Parent` to a `Child2`.  That won't work.

One option would be to use [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to inject the subclass name into `Parent`...

```
template<typename P, typename T>
class Parent
{
public:
  T x;
  T y;

  static P Inverse(Parent* A)
    {
      P B;
      B.x = -(A->x);
      B.y = -(A->y);
      return B;
    }
};
```

Where the template parameter `P` denotes the name of the subclass.  This could then be used as...

```
class Child1 : public Parent<Child1, int>{
};

class Child2 : public Parent<Child2, float>{
};

class ChildN : public Parent<ChildN, double>{
};

int main()
{
  Child2 A;
  A.x = 3.14;
  A.y = 15.92;
  Child2 B = Child2::Inverse(&A);
  std::cout << B.x << " : " << B.y << std::endl;
}
```